# How to check a value isexist or not in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table like customer_name and customer_category

customer category saved like "23|24|56|12|45|"  (category id)

**Sample Table Values**

customer_name  customer_category

Apple 34|23|12|

Orange 24|12|23|

Lemon   13|56|89|

I want to filter category like category_id=12

so my result will like Apple and Orange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Your Database is

```
customer_name   customer_category

Apple           34|23|12|

Orange          24|12|23|

Lemon           13|56|89|
```

and filter category like category_id=12

So try

`SELECT customer_name FROM myTable WHERE INSTR(customer_category,'12');`

Comment: @user1258544 its my pleasure...:-)

Answer (score 2):

Both answers above (with LIKE and INSTR) have a downside: In case your category list would be something like '34|23|121|89' and you would search with 'LIKE "%12%", you still would find the 121 entry.

Better Solution might be:

```
SELECT customer_name FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12', REPLACE(customer_category, '|', ',')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT customer_name FROM myTable WHERE customer_category LIKE '%12%';